# find the maximum value of some Summation

Tags: number-theory, finite-groups

Let A be a groups of some numbers: $$A = \big\{x_{1},x_{2},...,x_{n}\big\}$$
such that for any 1<= i <= n: $$0<= x_{i} <=1$$ and $$\sum_{i=0}^n x_{i} = 1$$

There is a formula for the maximum value of sum $$\sum_{i<j} x_{i}x_{j}$$?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The sum in question can be written
$$
\sum_{i<j}x_ix_j=\frac12\left[\left(\sum x_i\right)^2 - \sum_i x_i^2\right]
=\frac12\left[1-\sum_ix_i^2\right].\tag1
$$
You can use Lagrange multipliers to maximize the RHS of (1) over all $x_i$ subject to the constraint $\sum x_i=1$. The answer is $x_i=\frac1n$ for every $i$, and the maximum value for the RHS is $\frac12(1-\frac1n)$.

Comment: Or use the fact that the mean  does not exceed the quadratic mean.

Answer (score 0):

You have
$(\sum_i x_i)^2
=\sum_i x_i^2 +2\sum_{i<j} x_ix_j
$
so
$\sum_{i<j} x_ix_j
=\frac12((\sum_i x_i)^2-\sum_i x_i^2)
=\frac12(1-\sum_i x_i^2)
$.

Since
$\frac1{n}\sum_i x_i
\le (\frac1{n} \sum_i x_i^2)^{1/2}
$,
$\frac1{n} \sum_i x_i^2
\ge (\frac1{n}\sum_i x_i)^2
$
or
$ \sum_i x_i^2
\ge \frac1{n}(\sum_i x_i)^2
=\frac1{n}
$.

Therefore
$\sum_{i<j} x_ix_j
=\frac12(1-\sum_i x_i^2)
\le\frac12(1-\frac1{n})
$.